# What does `[ -f ... ]` mean?

Tags: shell, unix

Just want to know what is the below command do, or what `-f` means

```
if [ -f ${PDFFOLDER}/*.pdf ]; then
  rm ${PDFFOLDER}/*.pdf
fi
```

Comment: A couple of things to keep in mind: Options like `-f` are specific to each command. In this case, `-f` is actually an option to the `[` command. Second, your question refers to `-F`, but your question asks about `-f`. Those are two different strings -- and some commands could have both options with different meanings. UNIX is generally case-sensitive.

Comment: yeah, sorry its -f command.

Comment: No, it's the `-f` argument to the `[` command.

Answer (score 4):

Since `[ ]` and `test` aree the same command, the expressions within `[ ]` can be found in `man test`:

```
NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test

       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION
```

And there you also see:

> **-f** FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a regular file

So `if [ -f "$file" ]; then...` means: if the file `$file` exists and is a regular file (that is, not a directory or device file), then do whatever.

Comment: `test` is probably a builtin in most shells (particularly bash), so you should do `help test` and/or `help [`.

Answer (score 0):

The -f checks whether the given argument is a regular file or not. Check http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: how can we know if its a regular file or not?

Comment: @JohnPaul: By testing it with `[ -f filename ]`